# adapter between thicker and thinner AWG wires

Tags: connector, wire, adapter, solenoid-valve, awg

I'd like to connect two different AWG wires, sizes 18 and 24. Preferably made specifically for outdoors underground usage.

More to the facts, the 24 AWG is part of a 8-wire CAT 5E cable that I need too tuck into some [irrigation valve connectors](https://ixquick-proxy.com/do/spg/show_picture.pl?l=english&rais=1&oiu=http%3A%2F%2Fmultimedia.3m.com%2Fmws%2Fmedia%2F1099119P%2F3m-scotchlok-electrical-idc-316ir.jpg%3FboundedSize%3D310&sp=306a8c427df2f9f98dd412f7ecc325db) which is not supposed to be taking in the valve's thick wire and the thin 24 AWG wire together. This is what I am currently doing and I am having only trouble.

What sort of adapters should I be looking for ?

Comment: I would make a PCB with two types connectors.

Comment: Perhaps a wire thickness of 18 AWG at the valve is for some reason. It wouldn't be wrong if you connect to thicker wire, but not with tinner.

Comment: You should not have used Cat 5. You may need to dig it up and use the proper wire. It might help to use two in parallel and solder them before using this type of kit. They are available for various wire sizes: http://www.cesco.com/b2c/product/261052?gclid=CIenwp2Z-dICFYa2wAod_qME-Q

Comment: @GregoryKornblum what types of connectors did you have in mind ?

Comment: Rj45 for cat5 obviously and whatever for 18awg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use these quite often; [https://www.grainger.com/product/4FE28?gclid=Cj0KEQjwk-jGBRCbxoPLld_bp-IBEiQAgJaftemBgg3D7VVxKqJBI4doBh5jCrie0bHhEhx2V9w9Op8aAm9i8P8HAQ&cm_mmc=PPC:GOOGLEPLAA-*-Electrical-*-Wire%20Connectors-_-4FE28&AL!2966!3!166588026391!!!g!81032122797!&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!166588026391!!!g!81032122797!&ef_id=VxBI9gAABZPDSe7V:20170328142529:s](https://www.grainger.com/product/4FE28?gclid=Cj0KEQjwk-jGBRCbxoPLld_bp-IBEiQAgJaftemBgg3D7VVxKqJBI4doBh5jCrie0bHhEhx2V9w9Op8aAm9i8P8HAQ&cm_mmc=PPC:GOOGLEPLAA-_-Electrical-_-Wire%20Connectors-_-4FE28&AL!2966!3!166588026391!!!g!81032122797!&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!166588026391!!!g!81032122797!&ef_id=VxBI9gAABZPDSe7V:20170328142529:s)

The wire gauge range is 26 to 19 but I have had success with 18 gauge wire.

Another methode wouls be to solder and cover with shrink tubing.

[image]

Comment: Could you include a description and photo so that if the link stops working people know what type of connector you were referring to?

Comment: @ Kevin Reed; You can Google search; 3M 2-Port Moisture Resistant, Pigtail Insulation.